# I am trying to show databases that are already exist on postgres using (sql shell) but I am not able to show them

Tags: sql, postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im6jg.png)

I can't create databases and also add tables but when I am trying to list them or show the tables , it fails and give me the following statement " unrecognized configuration parameter "databases"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rySFl.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant data here as text instead of external images.  The error messages are localized, if you switch to English that would allow a lot more people to help.

Comment: If you use psql command line better try `\?`. This command show help for switch database, show tables, ...

Answer (score 5):

There is no command `show tables` or `show databases`.

To list databases use the command `\l`

To list tables use the command `\dt`